Grid-based pathfinding for a lot of agents: how to implement "Tight-Following"?
Note: the main problem has nothing to do with the TYPE of pathfinding algorithm (A*, flow-field etc), allow me to explain:
I have a 2d grid and a lot of agents moving around, I want it so that obviously no two agents occupy the same tile at the same time. Agent can be either standing on a tile or in-transit (moving from a tile to a neighboring tile).
I currently have a "reservation system" in place so that agent will request a tile from the pathfinding algorithm, which mark it as occupied, then the agent moves in animation to the new tile, and once it completely reached the new tile, the old tile is marked as unoccupied. However, this cause the following problem:
Consider the following situation where X=target, >=agent, .=empty tiles.
>>>>>..X

The agent closest to the target moves toward the target:
>>>>.>.X

Now that the tile the agent is standing on is free, the agent behind it move into it:
>>>.>>.X

And so on.
However there is a significant delay between image 2 to 3 where the tile would appears to be empty, so there is a large "gap" between the two agents.
Ideally step 2 would look like this:
.>>>>>.X

Where all agents advance towards the target with little to no gaps.
There's clearly a way to avoid this, the best example I can think of is in the classic flash game Boxhead where all the zombies would tightly follow each other despite the pathfinding also being clearly on a grid.
Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Just process all the agents in a single frame, and update positions of every agent? Next time you render, it'll look like every one of them moved.

Order the updates, head to tail.

If a entity has a successful reservation then you can mark its current square as available for reservation. Then check any entities that had a failed reservation.
If no entity can confirm their reservation (or after a max number of rechecks) then you are done and can perform the move.
The easiest way to implement this would be to just run your existing movement code multiple times per tick but freeze entities in place once they have moved in that tick.

You're running into a halting problem there if agents ever happen to follow each other in a circle.

@Tom I don't think there's a halting problem because entities can only move once per "tick" - but if you just naively check all entities with failed reservations instead of just failed reservations for the square in question you end up with an n^2 number of checks that could blow up on you.

You're right, if you properly implement max rechecks and run a pre-defined number runs per tick, you'll not run into a halting problem.

Your current approach amounts to each square having one of two states, locked or unlocked, and agents must lock squares they occupy and are moving to. This in turn means that any given square could have an agent entering it, or an agent leaving it, but not both at the same time.
The high-level approach I would take to avoid that limitation is to have a planning phase before the actual movement that determines where every agent is going to move, with a naive implementation looking vaguely like this:

For each agent, determine their preferred target square. This may be the same square they are currently occupying. Only factor in things like terrain for filtering possible target squares on this step, not whether the square is currently occupied by another agent. This calculation needs to be quick, as it will be your primary bottleneck for pathfinding.
For each square that would be occupied after all agents move, check if more than one agent wants to be in that square.
For each square with multiple agents that want to be there, determine which agent ‘wins’. This caculation also needs to be quick since it will be a hotpath on maps with lots of agents or lots of choke points. I would probably limit this to prioritizing agents that are not moving, and then just use the evaluation order (IOW, the first agent that tried to move to that square gets to move there).
For each agent whose movement was rejected in step 3, re-evaluate a different preferred target square, then re-check from step 2. Planning is over when step 3 does not result in any rejected movements.

This approach ensures that each agent will only move if they can actually occupy the target square after all agents have moved, which then means you don’t need to ‘roll back’ actual game state if an agent can’t be moved. Done right, it will allow a long line of adjacent agents to all advance one square in the same direction each update, but won’t require more complex state tracking on the map itself.
It also has the advantage that each part of the planning is trivial to parallelize (for example, the loop in step 1 can trivially compute each agent’s preferred square, because it doesn’t need to know about any other agent’s preferred square), which will give you better options for making the whole thing preform well.

Note that (3) can probably be optimized to the point that it's barely a separate step at all. Roughly speaking, that would mean each square has a flag that gets set if the agent occupying the square is not moving, and a separate atomic variable tracking which actor currently has priority for that square (you do an atomic compare-and-swap when an actor plans to move into a given square, or don't bother if the not-moving flag is set). You then have one global flag tracking whether any actor failed to acquire a square so that you know to try again.

You don't need to run the pathfinding algorithm multiple times.
Order the agents by distance to the player; your pathfinding algorithm can probably help you do that efficiently. Trigger the pathfinding for each agent in order, from the closest to the furthest. Ditch the reservation system, change the agent's tile immediately, freeing the previous tile.
By virtue of triggering in order, each agent can tightly follow the next agent closer to the player, since it will have already moved if possible.
If you want, you can add randomness to the order of same-distance agents, so a choke point (like an intersection) isn't always resolved in the same way.
This works for your described use case, with a single destination tile. I'm not sure it is expandable for multiple destinations.

Your reservations are currently expanding the claim (on land) that your agent has, but the agent is of a fixed size. When they take their claim, they will also release their claim on their current location. You're not accounting for that release.
Ensure that your reservations take into account which turn you're reserving them for, and only look at collisions with reservations that are relevant for the given turn.
To simplify the logic, you can consider the current location as a reservation on the current turn, which means that pretty much all your overlap detection can work with your reservation data structure.

You have the logic in your text description, but not in your code. Make your code understand that some agents are following other agents, like this:
Before doing any reservations, add a check if the square an agent wants to move to is occupied by another agent. If so, store yourself in a reference that other agent holds and set a "is_blocked" boolean on yourself to true.
Then, iterate over all agents where is_blocked is false.
When such an agent is done with his checks and reservations, check the other agent reference. If it's set, it means another agent wants to move to our old square, so signal that agent that the square is now free, and he can reserve it and initiate his movement.
Alternatively, you can simply leave the square as reserved instead of freeing and then reserving it again, and simply move the reference to the new agent.
Finally, set is_blocked to false for everyone.
If two different agents want to move to the same square occupied by a third agent, whoever is iterated last will move and the other will stand still - he will not be in the "is_blocked = false" iteration and he won't be called from the blocking agent.
Edge case: If your agents follow each other in a circle, nobody will move.

pseudocode:
struct agent {
   id, current_square, follower, is_blocked, next_square
}
struct square {
   id, reserved_by
}

// first loop
follow:
forall agents {
   if (next_square.reserved_by != null) {
      next_square.reserved_by.follower = this
      this.is_blocked = true
   }
}

// second loop
move:
forall agents where agent.is_blocked = false {
   checks_etc()
   next_square.reserved_by = this
   if (this.follower != null) {
      this.follower.move()
   } else {
      // nobody is following us, so our square is free again:
      current_square.reserved_by = null;
   }
}

